# Flutter Notifications to a specific person when a new row is created in database

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app based on Flutter, PHP and MySQL. I want to send notifications when one new row is created in database, to a user of app accordingly. To be more clear, as a user send interest in an item, database is updated. Now I want to send notification to the owner of the item. Owner and customer is using same app. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: use cloud function trigger for that.

Comment: Based on the tags you already found the answer: use firebase cloud messaging for sending notifications. You cannot do it with mysql and php.

Comment: Yes, I used firebase cloud messaging for the same and it worked perfectly.